# Setar Adapter dentro de uma Thread

Tags: android, android-studio, android-adapter

Estou tentando listar em um `RecyclerView` no `fragment`, mas o retorno da lista está em uma thread, não sei se estou fazendo algo errado mas não mostra nenhum registro.

No logcat não retorna nenhum erro, e a lista vem preenchida quando uso o Debug.

Segue método com o `Adapter` sendo setado dentro e passando a lista:

```
public void ListarArquivosdoFTP() {

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Recibo recibo = null;
                    classe_FTP ClienteFTP = new classe_FTP();
                    ClienteFTP.Conectar("ftp.meuhost.com.br", "usuario", "senha", 21);
                    FTPFile[] arquivos = ClienteFTP.Dir("/caminho");
                    if (arquivos != null) {
                        int length = arquivos.length;
                        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
                            FTPFile f = arquivos[i];
                            if (f.isFile()) {
                                recibo = new Recibo();
                                recibo.setRecibo(f.getName());
                                ArquivosFTP.add(recibo);
                            }
                        }
                        // Adapter
                        ReciboAdapter adapter = new ReciboAdapter(ArquivosFTP);
                        recyclerRecibo.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Meu ReciboAdapter:

```
public class ReciboAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReciboAdapter.ReciboHolder> {

    List<Recibo> listaRecibo;

    public ReciboAdapter(List<Recibo> listaRecibo) {
        this.listaRecibo = listaRecibo;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ReciboHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View vista = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lista_recibo, viewGroup, false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        vista.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return new ReciboHolder(vista);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReciboHolder reciboHolder, int i) {

        reciboHolder.txtRecibo.setText(listaRecibo.get(i).getRecibo().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listaRecibo.size();
    }

    public class ReciboHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView txtRecibo;

        public ReciboHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtRecibo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtRecibo);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Talvez vc precise do runOnUIThread()

Comment: Vou pesquisar e tentar implementar @Rocigno Medeiros.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tente dessa forma:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        recyclerRecibo.setAdapter(adapter);  
    }
});
```

Comment: Não funcionou, ficou a mesma coisa, o recyclerView sem registro e no logcat mostrou essa linha: E/RecyclerView: `No adapter attached; skipping layout`

Comment: Consegui, estava colocando em uma parte errada do código. vlw...